# Can't get access to my folder Working in VS2015 .NET 4.5.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

as you can see in the Picture i can't get access to my `App_Globalresources` and it keeps throwing errors

> The type or namespace name 'App_GlobalResources' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i tried everything (Restarting VS,Rebuilding the project) nothing works
and inside that folder is a `.rsex` file which i used to write some errors

[image]

is there anything that i can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using:

```
typeof(App_GlobalResources.Resource)
```

You should be using:

```
typeof(Resources.Resouce)
```

Working in VS2015 .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: is .NET 4.5.2 the latest version in visual studio 2015?(ps:thank you so much for the answer)

Comment: @MostafaBouzari I think the latest version is 4.6.1, we just haven't got round to updating!